# Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk from S3 gives "You do not have permission" -- who is "You"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I'm testing out AWS and Elastic Beanstalk and have Beanstalk running a version that was manually uploaded.

When I try to update the version via the command line, the command line returns ok but Beanstalk shows an error event.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-38 ~]$ /usr/bin/aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name play-app-test --version-label play-app-1051 --region us-east-1
True    play-app play-app-test.elasticbeanstalk.com       2015-09-27T04:05:25.486Z        2015-09-27T06:07:28.031Z                .....us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   e-jk8fyjd3dt    play-app-test    Grey    64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.play-app-1051Node.js
TIER    WebServer       Standard
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-35-38 ~]$
```

> Service:Amazon S3, Message:You do not have permission to perform the 's3:ListBucket' action. Verify that your S3 policies and your ACLs allow you to perform these actions.

Who exactly is it that does not have permission?

My Beanstalk environment's health permissions role is `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role` to which I've attached a policy granting access to S3 (I use the same policy for the user that uploaded the build to S3 and it worked there).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::play-app-builds"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::play-app-builds/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Beanstalk environment server's instance profile role is `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` which also has the above policy attached.

I turned on CloudTrail. It shows the `UpdateEnvironment` call but doesn't show any S3 calls after that. I'm not sure if CloudTrail shows failed calls or not.

Within S3 I turned logging on for the builds bucket but nothing has been logged.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are whoever `aws iam get-user` (with [no user name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.html)) says you are.

Comment: That prints out my deploy user who has the above policy, which grants `s3:ListBucket`..?

Comment: I suspect you've found some sort of bug and need to be talking to Amazon.

Comment: I attached the built-in policy `AmazonS3FullAccess` to the user and now deploy works (well, I had other policy errors, but the rest were very explanatory, only S3 seems to give vague errors). So, the problem is not with which user but with the policy, which I assumed was correct since the policy is used with uploading to S3. I'm going to mark your answer as correct--you did answer my primary question which is the user context. Thank you.  Now I still would like to figure out what I'm missing from my S3 policy. More experimenting. :-)